# rename filenames based on some calculations

Tags: rename

I have some files like this:

```
file.i001.trusted.txt
file.i002.trusted.txt
...
...
file.i212.trusted.txt
```

etc..

Now I want to change index numbers from i001 to i030 to A101 to A130 and i031 to i060 as A201 to A230..

I'm using "renamex" under FreeBSD primarily ( which has regex support )..

```
Usage: renamex [OPTIONS] filename ...
OPTIONS:
  -f, --file              Load file names from the file
  -l, --lowercase         Lowercase the file name
  -u, --uppercase         Uppercase the file name
  -s/PATTERN/STRING[/SW]  Replace the matching PATTERN with STRING.
                          The SW could be:
                          [i] ignore case when searching
                          [b] backward searching and replacing
                          [s] change file's suffix name
                          [r] PATTERN is regular expression
                          [e] PATTERN is extended regular expression
                          [g] replace all occurrences in the filename
                          [1-9] replace specified occurrences in the filename
  -R, --recursive         Operate on files and directories recursively
  -o, --owner OWNER       Change file's ownership (superuser only)
  -v, --verbose           Display verbose information
  -t, --test              Test only mode. Do not change any thing
  -h, --help              Display this help and exit
  -V, --version           Output version information and exit
  -A, --always            Always overwrite the existing files
  -N, --never             Never overwrite the existing files
Please see manpage regex(7) for the details of extended regular expression.
```

What do you suggest?

Edit: The ranges could be different. So it will not be 30 items always. For example A1 is 30 items, A2 is 40 items, A3 is 25 and so on...

Comment: Are there any gaps in the number ranges? Just wondering if you could do this with a simple script and `mv`.

Comment: There may be some files missing in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(file.)i(<->)(.trusted.txt)' '$1A$(($2+30+70*(($2-1)/30+1)))$3'
```

(remove the `-n` or pipe to `sh` when happy).

That would run:

```
mv -- file.i001.trusted.txt file.A101.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i002.trusted.txt file.A102.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i029.trusted.txt file.A129.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i030.trusted.txt file.A130.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i031.trusted.txt file.A201.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i032.trusted.txt file.A202.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i059.trusted.txt file.A229.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i060.trusted.txt file.A230.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i061.trusted.txt file.A301.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i062.trusted.txt file.A302.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i211.trusted.txt file.A801.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i212.trusted.txt file.A802.trusted.txt
```

You can replace `<->` with `<1-60>` if you only want to process the first 60 ones.

If it's not always batches of 30, you can always run several `zmvs`:

```
i=1 j=100
for batch (30 40 30 50) {
  zmv -n "(file.)i(<$i-$((i+batch-1))>)(.trusted.txt)" \
         '$1A$(($2+j))$3'
  ((i += batch, j += 100 - batch))
}
```

Which gives:

```
mv -- file.i001.trusted.txt file.A101.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i030.trusted.txt file.A130.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i031.trusted.txt file.A201.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i070.trusted.txt file.A240.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i071.trusted.txt file.A301.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i100.trusted.txt file.A330.trusted.txt
mv -- file.i101.trusted.txt file.A401.trusted.txt
[...]
mv -- file.i150.trusted.txt file.A450.trusted.txt
```